# React componentWillRecieveProps not called after mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have an isomorphic react app using react router 4 and redux.  I have a situation where I have multiple routes that use the same component (SectionFront).  This component is connected to the redux store.

I'm expecting the component's `componentWillRecieveProps()` to be called whenever the store's location is updated, however it is never called.

```
class SectionFront extends React.Component{


componentWillReceiveProps( nextprops ){
    console.log('next props... does not fire on location change');

}

render(){
    console.log('Render was called', this.props);

    return(
    <div>this is the section front</div>
    )
}

}



const mapDispatchToProps = {
loadSectionFront
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
console.log('This is called properly every time after the state changes', state);

return {
    sectionFront : state.sectionFront.payload,
    isLoading: state.sectionFront.loading,
    pathname: state.location.pathname
}
} 

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SectionFront)
```

Any thoughts as to why `componentWillReceiveProps()` does not get triggered even though the props are being updated and the render function is still called ?

Comment: Have u mutated the original state? Better post your reducer for modifying the location state as well.

Comment: Do you see any errors on console?